# Indexing policy is not being created along with collection in Cosmos DB

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing a database creation script using Java SDK and the indexing policy is not being created as expected (and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy)).

- JAVA SDK used: `com.microsoft.azure:azure-documentdb:2.4.0`
- Azure Cosmos DB emulator 2.2.2 for windows
- Current Cosmos DB installation in Azure Portal with SQL account

I construct the collection creation request with a JAVA library and the result (before the actual request) looks like this (`DocumentCollection::toJson()`):

```
{
    "uniqueKeyPolicy": {},
    "partitionKey":
    {
        "kind": "Hash",
        "paths": ["/playerId"]
    },
    "indexingPolicy":
    {
        "indexingMode": "Consistent",
        "automatic": true,
        "includedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/gameId/?",
                "indexes": [
                    {
                        "kind": "Range",
                        "dataType": "String"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "path": "/playerId/?",
                "indexes": [
                    {
                        "kind": "Range",
                        "dataType": "String"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "path": "/date/*",
                "indexes": [
                    {
                        "kind": "Range",
                        "dataType": "String"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/*"
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": "Games"
}
```

The request completes successful but if I check the actual indexing policy with data explorer or `DocumentClient.readCollection` it looks like this:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/gameId/?",
            "indexes": []
        },
        {
            "path": "/playerId/?",
            "indexes": []
        },
        {
            "path": "/date/*",
            "indexes": []
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the arrays for index definitions **are empty**. 
Then if I copy the indexing policy from SDK-generated output and manually paste it in Emulator or Portal 'Scale and settings' window for created collection the update outcome becomes the following:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/gameId/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/playerId/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/date/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

So the indexes are being created (although with extra `Number` entry as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245111/cosmos-db-indexing-policy-settings)). 
Am I doing something wrong with a creation script?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [github source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java/blob/master/documentdb-examples/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/examples/CollectionCrudSamples.java) and refer to below code which works for me.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateCollectionTest {
    //
    static private String YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
    static private String YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY = "***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT,
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY,
                new ConnectionPolicy(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection();
        collection.set("id", "game");


        IndexingPolicy indexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy();
        Collection<IncludedPath> includedPaths = new ArrayList<IncludedPath>();
        IncludedPath includedPath = new IncludedPath();
        includedPath.setPath("/gameId/?");
        Collection<Index> indexes = new ArrayList<Index>();

        Index stringIndex = Index.Range(DataType.String);
        stringIndex.set("precision", -1);
        indexes.add(stringIndex);

        Index numberIndex = Index.Range(DataType.Number);
        numberIndex.set("precision", -1);
        indexes.add(numberIndex);

        includedPath.setIndexes(indexes);
        includedPaths.add(includedPath);
        indexingPolicy.setIncludedPaths(includedPaths);

        collection.setIndexingPolicy(indexingPolicy);

        ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> createColl = client.createCollection("dbs/db", collection, null);


    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please add an `excludedPath` policy as your example fails without it.
2. Could you please paste a result from `Scale and Settings` of DB explorer after you create your collection with the snippet? Your example also gives me an empty array :(